# What does "quote unquote" mean?

Tags: quotations

I understand the need to quote someone without using your hands. Example:

> Alice said Bob *quote* intervened *unquote*.

This, I understand. Her use of the word "intervened" was a direct quote.

**My question:**

Some times, someone will say

> quote unquote

in the middle of a sentence, with no word in between. What's the purpose of this?

---

PS. The word "quote" just lost all meaning in my head. Sorry if my post has the same effect on you.

Comment: About your PS: this is called [semantic satiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_satiation).

Comment: It may be that the signal _quote_ _unquote_ means that the following sentence or phrase or even paragraph is a direct quote, until the speaker signals or says otherwise that the quoted portion has stopped. But I think @snailplane just wrote an answer saying something similar to this, if I read her answer correctly

Comment: These 'quotes' don't need to be *direct quotes* they can be *scare quotes*.  Thus, the quoted *intervened* may be an indication that it is being used liberally or loosely or euphemistically.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Quote* and *unquote* are verbal representations of quotation marks, exactly as you suggest in the beginning of your question.  In your first example, they take the place of the quotation marks directly:

> Alice said Bob **quote** *intervened* **unquote**.
>
> Alice said Bob **“***intervened***”**.

In your second example, they indicate that the following (or occasionally preceding) word or phrase is to be understood as though it's a quote:

> Alice said Bob **quote unquote** *intervened*.
>
> Alice said Bob **“***intervened***”**.

When this occurs, the quoted phrase is probably set off intonationally, so you can hear where the boundaries are despite the word order.

Either version can be used with the same meaning, but I think the latter version is especially associated with so-called [“scare quotes”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes).  As Wikipedia says:

> When referred to as “scare quotes”, the quotation marks are suggested to imply skepticism of or disagreement with the quoted terminology.

To my ear, this is especially likely when *quote unquote* precede the “quoted” phrase.  It's a verbal signal of irony.

Comment: I never heard the expression 'scare quote' before.... So... I guess you learn something every day.

Answer (score 5):

The phrase "quote unquote" denotes irony or sarcasm

A quotation mark before and after a  word means that it is a verbatim recitation.

I have a different interpretation that snailplane's.

The  sentence, Alice said Bob quote intervened unquote, would not be  used in American speech because intervened is a verb. It  is something Bob might have done, but not anything he is likley to have verbalized and therefore, in my opinion, not a potential quotation.

However, Alice said Bob quote unquote"intervened", means that Bob somehow became involved in a situation perhaps half-heartedly, perhaps ineffectively, perhaps interjecting himself  in a situation that was not his business.

Comment: I've used _quote unquote_ multiple times when reporting verbatim speech, as have many of my friends and acquaintances.